# Migrating Sharepoint server 3.0 Document Library to SPF 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

How can i migrate SP Service 3.0 (document library or sites) to SPF 2010?

Is there any way for copying all the sites with content and metadata to SPF 2010? We have got quite a few sites in SP Service 3.0 which contain alot of documents, we want to migrate everything including sites layout and documents to SPF 2010.

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to is better known as a SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2010 Upgrade / Migration and can be accomplished in a few ways.

- The preferred method is the [content database detach / attach](http://blogs.technet.com/b/nitinsha/archive/2010/07/27/migration-from-sharepoint-2007-to-sharepoint-2010.aspx) method
  that brings all of your content over (provided your 2007 farm is
  properly patched first).
- You can use third party tools like [DocAve](http://www.avepoint.com/sharepoint-migration-tools/) to selectively upgrade and migrate content
- You can use freeware tools like (Gary LaPoint's [SharePoint Extensions](http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/downloads/)) to migrate lists individually
- Or, if you only care about the documents themselves and not the metadata, you can simply open Explorer view at the root of your 2007 doclib and on the 2010 doclib and drag and drop all the files over.  All metadata is lost this way but the files are moved.

Microsoft has a few [resources](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff770990.aspx) on this this topic but there are more on [blogs](http://sharepointgeorge.com/2009/upgrading-content-db-sharepoint-2010-part-1-preupgradecheck/).